# Heap Remove and Rebuild method? (Java)

Tags: java, heap

Something is wrong with either my remove or rebuild method, when I first remove the lowest number, then the max number goes to the front of the queue. It is a heap using an array list.

```
   public E remove() throws HeapException {
       E root = tree.get(0);
       tree.set(0, tree.get(tree.size() - 1));

       currentObjCount = tree.size() - 1;
       tree.remove(tree.size() - 1);        
       rebuild(0, currentObjCount);

       return root;
   }

   private void swap(int place, int parent) {
       E tmp = tree.get(pos);
       tree.set(place, tree.get(parent));
       tree.set(parent, tmp);
   }

   private void rebuild(int root, int eSize) {
       eSize = tree.size();

       if (root * 2 > eSize && root * 2 + 1 > eSize) {
           child = 2 * root + 1;
           if (root * 2 + 1 <= eSize) {
               if (tree.get(child + 1).compareTo(tree.get(child)) > 0) {
                   child++;
               }
               if (tree.get(root).compareTo(tree.get(child)) < 0) {
                   swap(root, child); 
                   rebuild(child, eSize);
               }
           }
```

My output:

```
Inserting

8 
-4 8 
-4 8 8 
-4 -1 8 8 
-4 -1 8 8 8 
-10 -1 -4 8 8 8 

Removing

8 -1 -4 8 8 
8 -1 -4 8 
8 -1 -4 
-4 -1 
-1
```

I think that it is the rebuild method. Its probably the comparison signs but if it is, I don't know which ones.

Comment: Not responsible for your problem, but it's pointless for the `rebuild()` method to accept `eSize` as a parameter when the very first thing that method does is replace whatever value was passed with one it computes itself.

Comment: Your `rebuild()` method is truncated in the question, which is clearer now, with proper formatting.  Is anything other than some closing braces missing?

Comment: The main issue appears to be that you have reversed the needed sense of the comparisons in the outermost `if` statement in the `rebuild` method.  You appear to want `if (root * 2 < eSize && root * 2 + 1 < eSize)`, instead.  I suspect that even then it's not quite right, but I can't be sure because I don't know what's been truncated from the method.